# Creating a dataframe in R from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

The Univeristiy of Amsterdam has published a dataframe in Datacamp as part of an online course program. Unfortunately Datacamp does not allow to read in the data again. It needs to be solved inside R.  When check the data it looks like the dataframe is there but in a slight weird form. Everything seems to be there but I do not know how to unreavel it.

From the checks I did, it looks like there is one column name:

```
Id.Finished.consent.birthyear.education.country.......
```

I think it should have been column name

```
[1] Id
[2] Finished
[3] consent
```

etc.

I would like to have them as separate columns with there corresponding data.

How can I reconstruct the dataframe?

```
colnames(data)
is.data.frame(data)
summary(data)
head(data, 3)
sum(data$Finished)
```

```
colnames(data)
[1] `"Id.Finished.consent.birthyear.education.country.ST_CT.ST_ct.ST_T.ST_t.ST_NT.ST_nt.ST.timing_1.ST.timing_2.ST.timing_3.ST.timing_4.math6.math2.math3.math4.math8.math9.ST.end.of.test.gender.ST_ind.ST_biological_1.ST_men_better_3.ST_abstract_1.ST_mind_calculations_1.ST_scientist_1"`
is.data.frame(data)
[1] TRUE
summary(data)
```

```
Id.Finished.consent.birthyear.education.country.ST_CT.ST_ct.ST_T.ST_t.ST_NT.ST_nt.ST.timing_1.ST.timing_2.ST.timing_3.ST.timing_4.math6.math2.math3.math4.math8.math9.ST.end.of.test.gender.ST_ind.ST_biological_1.ST_men_better_3.ST_abstract_1.ST_mind_calculations_1.ST_scientist_1
     10;1;1;1984;2;111;1;1;;;;;98435;477331;481.74;35;2;6;5;3;4;1;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;4   : 1                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     11;1;1;1980;5;111;1;1;;;;;20632;140506;144.17;35;1;1;5;3;4;5;1;1;1;3;2;3;2;4   : 1                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     12;1;1;1978;6;111;;;1;1;;;33487;197415;199134;39;1;2;3;5;4;5;1;1;1;5;5;3;4;5   : 1                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     13;1;1;1983;4;111;1;1;;;;;4743;1474.217;1475.655;22;4;2;5;3;4;2;1;1;1;5;5;3;5;5: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     14;1;1;1989;6;111;;;;;1;1;18146;1298.57;1301.565;16;5;6;5;3;4;2;1;1;1;3;2;3;3;3: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     15;1;1;1994;5;111;;;1;1;;;4635;1005.731;1007.618;59;4;6;5;1;4;1;1;2;1;5;5;3;5;5: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     (Other)                                                                        :67                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    head(data, 3)

    Id.Finished.consent.birthyear.education.country.ST_CT.ST_ct.ST_T.ST_t.ST_NT.ST_nt.ST.timing_1.ST.timing_2.ST.timing_3.ST.timing_4.math6.math2.math3.math4.math8.math9.ST.end.of.test.gender.ST_ind.ST_biological_1.ST_men_better_3.ST_abstract_1.ST_mind_c ...
    1                                                                                                                                                                                    1;1;1;1977;7;187;;;;;1;1;12176;240756;241507;31;5;2;5;1;4;5;1;2;1;5;5;5;5;5
    2                                                                                                                                                                                      2;1;1;1990;7;61;1;1;;;;;2877;248239;248909;33;1;2;5;1;4;2;1;1;1;5;5;5;5;5
    3                                                                                                                                                                                     3;1;1;1980;3;111;;;1;1;;;41605;639774;652005;8;1;2;5;2;4;2;1;1;1;5;5;5;5;5
    sum(data$Finished)
    [1] 0
```

Comment: Assuming that this is a csv file or similar (you didn't specified it in your question),
and that the problem is that columns are separated with a dot instead of a semicolon, the following code could fix the original file, if read as text, and then saving the modified text and loading it should work: `stringr::str_replace_all(text, "(?<=\\D)\\.", ";")`. This regex replaces all dots immediately after text (not numbers) to be replaced with a semicolon. Or you could do this on any other text editor.

Comment: `stringr` seems to be hitting a limit against first line,  `nchar(nchar(line1)
[1] 278   0`,that is likely 256 char, whereas `gsub('\\.', ';', line1, perl = TRUE)[1]` doesn't limit. so stringr terminates line 1 with `ST_ind;ST_biological_1.ST_men_better_3.ST_abstract_1.ST_mind_calculations_1.ST_scientist_1` and gsub terminates with `ST_ind;ST_biological_1;ST_men_better_3;ST_abstract_1;ST_mind_calculations_1;ST_scientist_1`, which seems better, but ...

Comment: So, I'd read in headerless or skip = 1, find how many fields there are with sep=";", and puzzle over what the data author's naming convention was, fiddling with `gsub(` then name the columns.

Comment: I am not clear what the raw data being read looks like, but it seems like reading the comments above that the header is period (`"."`) separated and maybe the main data is semi-colon (`";"`) separated?  I've run into analogous situations before and solved it be reading the data file twice using either `read.table()` or `read.delim()`.  One just reads the single row that is the header column names, and the other reads the data, and then `colnames(df_data) <- as.character(df_header[1, ])` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Using your six lines above saved (in editor) as .csv, and bring comments into this

```
line1 = readLines(textConnection('Id.Finished.consent.birthyear.education.country.ST_CT.ST_ct.ST_T.ST_t.ST_NT.ST_nt.ST.timing_1.ST.timing_2.ST.timing_3.ST.timing_4.math6.math2.math3.math4.math8.math9.ST.end.of.test.gender.ST_ind.ST_biological_1.ST_men_better_3.ST_abstract_1.ST_mind_calculations_1.ST_scientist_1
'))

mult_delimiter = read.csv('mult_delimiter.csv', header = FALSE, skip = 1, sep = ';')
dim(mult_delimiter)
[1]  6 30
```

so looking for thirty names.

```
possible_names = gsub('\\.', ';', line1, perl = TRUE)[1]
> strsplit(possible_names, split = ';')
[[1]]
 [1] "Id"                     "Finished"               "consent"               
 [4] "birthyear"              "education"              "country"               
 [7] "ST_CT"                  "ST_ct"                  "ST_T"                  
[10] "ST_t"                   "ST_NT"                  "ST_nt"                 
[13] "ST"                     "timing_1"               "ST"                    
[16] "timing_2"               "ST"                     "timing_3"              
[19] "ST"                     "timing_4"               "math6"                 
[22] "math2"                  "math3"                  "math4"                 
[25] "math8"                  "math9"                  "ST"                    
[28] "end"                    "of"                     "test"                  
[31] "gender"                 "ST_ind"                 "ST_biological_1"       
[34] "ST_men_better_3"        "ST_abstract_1"          "ST_mind_calculations_1"
[37] "ST_scientist_1" 

names_vec = vector(mode = 'character', length = 30L)
names_vec[1:12] = strsplit(possible_names, split = ';')[[1]][1:12]# a guess
names_vec
 [1] "Id"        "Finished"  "consent"   "birthyear" "education" "country"  
 [7] "ST_CT"     "ST_ct"     "ST_T"      "ST_t"      "ST_NT"     "ST_nt"    
[13] ""          ""          ""          ""          ""          ""         
[19] ""          ""          ""          ""          ""          ""         
[25] ""          ""          ""          ""          ""          ""         

paste0(strsplit(possible_names, split = ';')[[1]][13], '_', strsplit(possible_names, split = ';')[[1]][14])
[1] "ST_timing_1"

paste0(strsplit(possible_names, split = ';')[[1]][27], '_', strsplit(possible_names, split = ';')[[1]][28],'_', paste0(strsplit(possible_names, split = ';')[[1]][29], '_', strsplit(possible_names, split = ';')[[1]][30]))
[1] "ST_end_of_test"
```

and continue, assigning to names_vec then `colnames(`.